# Easy method of determining if a polynomial over $\Bbb{Z}$ has any quadratic factors with rational coefficients

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

There is an easy method of determining whether a monic polynomial

$$\sum_0^n a_k x^k$$

with all $a_k \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $a_n = 1$ has any integer roots.

At least it is easy if you can factor  the integer $a_0$ -- you just try $\pm$ all possible factors of $a_0$.

There is an easy method of determining if a non-monic polynomial has any rational root.
For example, 
$$ 30x^3 -7x^2 -7x + 2$$

has roots $$\left\{\frac25, \frac13, -\frac12 \right\}$$

You can find these by trying very fraction $\pm \frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ divides $\lvert a_0\rvert$ and $q$ divides $\lvert a_n\rvert$.  It takes a bit longer than for integer roots, but it is relatively inspiration-free (other than the factoring, again).  In both cases, the method either finds a root or shows there are none.

But is there an method of determining if a polynomial over $\Bbb{Z}$ has any quadratic factors with rational coefficients (and finding one of those factors)?  For example,

$$x^6 - 16x^5 + 87 x^4 -468 x^3 + 2057 x^2 -2955 x + 240$$

has a factor $(x^2-15x+48)$ and one can determine what that the constant term had to be a factor of $240$.  But is there an easy rule of thumb for what to try for the linear term?

In other words, is there an algorithm involving trying out a finite number of potential factors, to determine if one of them works?

Comment: Well, one can certainly do long division by $x^2+b x +48$ and see what the remainder $0$ gives for $b$. You will have a couple of polynomials in $b$ that need to be $0$. You can take their gcd (pretty fast)  and then deal with a lower degree equation on $b$. So it is doable.

Comment: That reduces the problem to finding a if there exists a rational  root of a degree $n-2$ polynomial in $b$, for each value of $c$ that is a factor of $a_0$.  (It is only one equation, because the remainder is only one polynomial over the original). Although this is much more work than for the rational case, it shows  there is a finite-steps algorithm, so it answers the question.

Comment: I think it is two equations, since the remainder will have coefficients by $x$ and a free term.

Comment: Yes, @Lev Borisov, that is right, and I did not notice that.  I wonder whether that could reduce the annoying amount of recursive calculations (each yielding a polynomial of degree 2 less than the last) needed.

Comment: It could certainly make these calculations easier. I suspect that in many cases the gcd would be $1$.